# Word Document Print from specific Tray

Tags: vb.net

I need to print the word active document into the specific tray.
for example if user click the button letter the document should print from tray 2.
at the moment I am using this basic piece of code

```
Dim word As Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
        Dim pd As New PrintDialog()
        pd.PrinterSettings = New PrinterSettings()
            If pd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            word.PrintOut()
        End If
```

i had managed to do some work related to this if i use the property prindocument(). somthing like

Dim pkSource As Printing.PaperSource
            Dim printDoc As New PrintDocument
            ' AddHandler printDoc.PrintPage

```
        printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = strPrinter
        For Each pkSource In printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSources
            If pkSource.RawKind = "261" Then


                printDoc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource.RawKind = pkSource.RawKind
                Dim psize As Printing.PaperSize = printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Item(5)
                printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize
                printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.AllPages
                'AddHandler printDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintDoc_PrintPage
                printDoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = num_copies
                printDoc.PrinterSettings.Duplex = Duplex.Default
                AddHandler printDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
                'PrintDocument1 = oWord.ActiveDocument
                Try
                    'PrintDocument1.Print()
                    printDoc = app
                Catch ex As System.Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try

                'printDoc.Print()
                ' MsgBox("printed")
                RemoveHandler printDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
            End If
        Next
```

But I don't want to use print document as I need to print the activate word document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty certain you cannot add content to the PrintDocument object - but it does expose events you can manipulate at the page level.

With that said, it appears you are working within Word here.  Why not use the word object's ActiveDocument to set the trays (firstPageTray and otherPagesTray) there?

Comment: Thansk For reply. sorry i am not good with that if you can please give me any example it will be very helpfull, to work with (firstPageTray and otherPagesTray) ... thanks

Comment: Dim wd As Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
        Dim doc As Word.Document = wd.ActiveDocument
        doc.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = 262
        doc.PageSetup.OtherPagesTray = 262
        'doc.PrintOut()

Comment: That should work.  The pointer value is a long.  There are ways to get lists of tray IDs (that long integer) as well as tray names.